# how to use ignorecase in interface if only one field requires it

Tags: java, spring, mongorepository

I have a class 'City' which has first element as String city_name and second element as its country which is a member of Country object i.e.

```
public static class City {
        @Id
        private String id;
        private String city;
        @DBRef
        private Country country;
}
```

I have created an MongoDB Interface which implements the MongoRepository class as below:

```
public interface CityRepository extends MongoRepository<City, String>{

    List <City> findByCityAndCountryIgnoreCase(String city, Country country);
}
```

When I try to run this, I get an error that the compiler expects a String instead of Country class. I understand that I don't want to apply IgnoreCase on Country but only on city name; but how do I create my function to achieve this?

Comment: findByCityIgnoreCaseAndCountry()?

Comment: Thanks - that was stupid of me! :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the different flavors:-

**Ignore case for city only:-**

```
List <City> findByCityIgnoreCaseAndCountry (String city, Country country);
```

**Ignore case for country only:-**

```
List <City> findByCityAndCountryIgnoreCase (String city, Country country);
```

**For both city and country i.e. for all properties:-**

```
List <City> findByCityAndCountryAllIgnoreCase (String city, Country country);
```

[Spring Data Mongo Ignore Case](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.7.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html)

> // Enabling ignoring case for an individual property   List
>   findByLastnameIgnoreCase(String lastname);
>   // Enabling ignoring case for all suitable properties   List
>   findByLastnameAndFirstnameAllIgnoreCase(String lastname, String
>   firstname);

Comment: Thanks @notionquest